# Shouldn't Up-Votes be locked in unless the OP is the one to edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, up-votes

As it stands now, 5 minutes after voting on a question/answer, our votes are locked and we can't retract our votes.

But, as soon as **anyone** makes an edit, we can retract our **up**-votes

**Is this really fair?**

Let's say, If I write an answer, and I receive 10 up-votes, is it right that after *Joe* edits my answer, the up-voters can now change their vote?

I understand that down-votes should be unlocked, because *Joe* might have cleaned the post and therefore the reason for down-voting is gone. But what's the reason for unlocking up-votes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like an unnecessary overcomplication.

Compare:

1. You can not change a vote on a post after five minutes unless it's edited.

**- OR -**

2. You can not change a vote on a post after five minutes unless:

   - The OP edits the post, in which case you can change both upvotes or downvotes.
     **- OR -**
   - Another user edits the post, in which case you can only change a downvote.

For what benefit is this complication gaining? We're going from something extremely simple to explain to something that's somewhat arbitrary.

What harm is done when you unlock all votes? I don't have any data but I'm going to bet that in *most* cases, the people voting on posts rarely return to even notice that the post has been edited, let alone return to change their vote.

If your answer really attained 10 upvotes, surely you should be unconcerned about people retracting their votes due to an edit by a third party. If someone else edits your post and makes it worse, this should be rolled back and, one would hope, the voters would see that the destructive edits were made and repair them before casting votes against the post.

Unless you can show this being abused in a major way, I don't see the benefit of making the rules more complex to prevent an extremely rare situation.

Comment: My question was, in what case would it make sense for upvotes to be unlocked? I guess i want clear

Comment: Getting more information and realizing that the answer is not as good as you originally thought it was. Nothing makes a post permanently good any more than permanently bad.

Comment: @Abochur The body of your question makes it seem like you're requesting a feature, which probably explains the downvotes.

Comment: @Catija according to that, votes should never be locked. That's not what I'm discussing! I'm saying, if i make a post, and joe edits it, according to the logic of locking votes until an edit happens, it doesn't make sense to unlock upvotes because obviously joe made a bad edit

Comment: That's not true at all. The benefit to locking votes is to encourage people to think before they vote. If they don't, their vote is stuck until the post is edited.

Comment: I see your answer as agreement with my point. And the only reason why you wouldn't implement it, is because it could cause unnecessary complications.

Comment: @Abochur You can see it however you like. I don't agree with you but if it makes you feel better, go ahead and feel that way.

Answer (score 1):

Upvotes being removed could imply that the answer is no longer useful, as is the case when newer information is available in newer answers. This could be applicable to questions where the answers would change over time.

Also it's possible that the original answerer no longer uses stacks. So it has to be someone else doing the edits on the older answer, not necessarily making it bad, but adding some lines that would mention that the particular solution is no longer applicable or some note linking to the more relevant newer answer.

So in order to promote the newer answers to the top, I do occasionally remove my upvotes on the older ones when I come across some. I have done so on at least superuser and android stacks.

Comment: “So in order to promote the newer answers to the top” - This only affects the order displayed to you

Comment: @Ramhound Incorrect. It affects the order sorted by votes, to everyone.